# How To Transmit Data from two NRF24L01 transmitters into an NRF24L01 receiver?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller

I'm trying to sync two NRF24L01 transceivers acting as transmitters into an NRF24L01 acting as receiver.

Both transmitters will are connected with individual sensors, and the data of those sensors are what I'm trying to transmit into the receiver, however, collectively and simultaneously. What results is this collision of incomprehensible data coming from both transmitters.

[image: Sample of Serial Monitor]

My code are as follows. As you can see in the code of the receiver below, I tried separating the packets of data from the transmitters.

```
    #include <SPI.h>
    #include "RF24.h"

    RF24 myRadio (8, 9);
    byte addresses[6] = {"1Node"};


    int accelgyroscope[3];

    int ax, ay, az;
    int gx, gy, gz;

    int LED_GREEN = A3;
    int LED_RED = A2;


    struct Pack {
      int data1;
      int data2;
      int data3;
      int data4;
      int data5;
      int accx;
      int accy;
      int accz;
      int con1;
      int con2;
      int data11;
      int data22;
      int data33;
      int data44;
      int data55;
      int accxx;
      int accyy;
      int acczz;

    } packet;



    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);

      myRadio.begin();
      myRadio.setChannel(108);
      myRadio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
      myRadio.openReadingPipe(1, addresses[0]);
      myRadio.openReadingPipe(2, addresses[1]);
      myRadio.startListening();

      Serial.print("LABEL,F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,X,Y,Z,C1,C2");
      Serial.println();

      pinMode(LED_GREEN, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(LED_RED, OUTPUT);

    }

    void loop() {
      if ( myRadio.available())   {

        analogWrite(LED_GREEN, 1023);
        analogWrite(LED_RED, 0);

        myRadio.read( &packet, sizeof(packet) );

        Serial.print("TRANSMITTER 1:  ");
        Serial.print(", ");
        Serial.print(packet.data1);
        Serial.print(", ");
        Serial.print(packet.data2);
        Serial.print(", ");
        Serial.print(packet.data3);
        Serial.print(", ");
        Serial.print(packet.data4);
        Serial.print(", ");
        Serial.print(packet.data5);

        Serial.print(", ");
        Serial.print(packet.accx);
        Serial.print(", ");

        Serial.print(packet.accy);
        Serial.print(", ");
        Serial.print(packet.accz);
        Serial.print(", ");

        Serial.print(packet.con1);
        Serial.print(", ");
        Serial.print(packet.con2);

        Serial.print("  ");
        Serial.print("TRANSMITTER 2:  ");
        Serial.print(", ");
        Serial.print(packet.data11);
        Serial.print(", ");
        Serial.print(packet.data22);
        Serial.print(", ");
        Serial.print(packet.data33);
        Serial.print(", ");
        Serial.print(packet.data44);
        Serial.print(", ");
        Serial.print(packet.data55);

        Serial.print(", ");
        Serial.print(packet.accxx);
        Serial.print(", ");

        Serial.print(packet.accyy);
        Serial.print(", ");
        Serial.print(packet.acczz);
        Serial.print(", ");

        Serial.println();

      }
      else
      {
        analogWrite(LED_RED, 1023);
        analogWrite(LED_GREEN, 0);
      }



    }
```

Here is the code to my first transmitter.

```
#include <SPI.h> //libraries para sa nrf24l01
#include "RF24.h" //

#include <Wire.h> // MPU-6050 I2C LIBRARY
#include <I2Cdev.h> //
#include <MPU6050.h> //



#define flex_1 A0 //declaring ng variable tsaka pin assignment ng 5 flex sensors
#define flex_2 A1
#define flex_3 A2
#define flex_4 A3
#define flex_5 A6

MPU6050 accelgyro; // variable ng mpu6050

int16_t ax, ay, az; // variables para accelerometer and gyroscope
int16_t gx, gy, gz;

int pinx=2; // pin assignment ng contact sensors
int piny=3;

RF24 myRadio (8, 9); // CSN AT CE PIN ASSIGNMENT
byte addresses[6] = {"1Node"}; // address ng both transmitter and receiver

// structure para masend ng inorder
struct Pack {
  int data1;
  int data2;
  int data3;
  int data4;
  int data5;
  int accx;
  int accy;
  int accz;
  int con1;
  int con2;
} packet;


void setup() {

  Serial.begin(38400); // para magamit ang serial monitor 
  Serial.println(F("RF24/Simple Transmit data Test"));

  Wire.begin(); // 

  accelgyro.initialize(); // para maread ang pin ng mpu6050

  pinMode(pinx, INPUT);
digitalWrite(pinx, HIGH);
pinMode(piny, INPUT);
digitalWrite(piny, HIGH);
/*
    accelgyro.setXAccelOffset(2825);
    accelgyro.setYAccelOffset(457);
    accelgyro.setZAccelOffset(645);
*/
  myRadio.begin(); // nrf24l01
  myRadio.setChannel(108); 
  myRadio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
  myRadio.openWritingPipe(addresses[0]);
}

void loop() {
  packet.data1 = analogRead(flex_1); 
  packet.data1=map(packet.data1, 450, 950, 3000, 4000); 
  packet.data2 = analogRead(flex_2);
  packet.data2=map(packet.data2, 450, 950, 3300, 4500);
  packet.data3 = analogRead(flex_3);
  packet.data3=map(packet.data3, 450, 950, 3000, 4000);
  packet.data4 = analogRead(flex_4);
  packet.data4=map(packet.data4, 450, 950, 3000, 4000);
  packet.data5 = analogRead(flex_5);
  packet.data5=map(packet.data5, 450, 950, 3000, 4000);
  packet.accx=ax;
  packet.accy=ay;
  packet.accz=az;
  packet.con1=digitalRead(pinx);
  packet.con2=digitalRead(piny);

  accelgyro.getMotion6(&ax, &ay, &az, &gx, &gy, &gz);


  if (myRadio.write(&packet, sizeof(packet))) {
    Serial.print(F("flex1 = "));
    Serial.print(packet.data1);
    Serial.print(F(" flex2 = "));

    Serial.print(packet.data2);
    Serial.print(F(" flex3 = "));
    Serial.print(packet.data3);
    Serial.print(F(" flex4 = "));
    Serial.print(packet.data4);
    Serial.print(F(" flex5 = "));
    Serial.print(packet.data5);

    Serial.print(F(" accx = "));
    Serial.print(packet.accx);
    Serial.print(F(" accy = "));
    Serial.print(packet.accy);
    Serial.print(F(" accz = "));
    Serial.print(packet.accz);
    Serial.print(F(" con1 = "));
    Serial.print(packet.con1);
    Serial.print(F(" con2 = "));
    Serial.print(packet.con2);

    Serial.println();
  } 

  else {
    Serial.print(F("Send failed."));
  }

}
```

And here is the other transmitter:

```
#include <SPI.h> //libraries para sa nrf24l01
#include "RF24.h" //

#include <Wire.h> // MPU-6050 I2C LIBRARY
#include <I2Cdev.h> //
#include <MPU6050.h> //



#define flex_1 A0 //declaring ng variable tsaka pin assignment ng 5 flex sensors
#define flex_2 A1
#define flex_3 A2
#define flex_4 A3
#define flex_5 A6

MPU6050 accelgyro; // variable ng mpu6050

int16_t ax, ay, az; // variables para accelerometer and gyroscope
int16_t gx, gy, gz;

int pinx=2; // pin assignment ng contact sensors
int piny=3;

RF24 myRadio (8, 9); // CSN AT CE PIN ASSIGNMENT
byte addresses[6] = {"1Node"}; // address ng both transmitter and receiver

// structure para masend ng inorder
struct Pack {
  int data11;
  int data22;
  int data33;
  int data44;
  int data55;
  int accxx;
  int accyy;
  int acczz;

} packet1;


void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600); // para magamit ang serial monitor 
  Serial.println(F("RF24/Simple Transmit data Test"));

  Wire.begin(); // 

  accelgyro.initialize(); // para maread ang pin ng mpu6050

  pinMode(pinx, INPUT);
digitalWrite(pinx, HIGH);
pinMode(piny, INPUT);
digitalWrite(piny, HIGH);
/*
    accelgyro.setXAccelOffset(2825);
    accelgyro.setYAccelOffset(457);
    accelgyro.setZAccelOffset(645);
*/
  myRadio.begin(); // nrf24l01
  myRadio.setChannel(108); 
  myRadio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
  myRadio.openWritingPipe(addresses[1]);
}

void loop() {
  packet1.data11 = analogRead(flex_1); 
  packet1.data11=map(packet1.data11, 450, 950, 3000, 4000); 
  packet1.data22 = analogRead(flex_2);
  packet1.data22=map(packet1.data22, 450, 950, 3300, 4500);
  packet1.data33 = analogRead(flex_3);
  packet1.data33=map(packet1.data33, 450, 950, 3000, 4000);
  packet1.data44 = analogRead(flex_4);
  packet1.data44=map(packet1.data44, 450, 950, 3000, 4000);
  packet1.data55 = analogRead(flex_5);
  packet1.data55=map(packet1.data55, 450, 950, 3000, 4000);
  packet1.accxx=ax;
  packet1.accyy=ay;
  packet1.acczz=az;

  accelgyro.getMotion6(&ax, &ay, &az, &gx, &gy, &gz);


  if (myRadio.write(&packet1, sizeof(packet1))) {
    Serial.print(F("flex1 = "));
    Serial.print(packet1.data11);
    Serial.print(F(" flex2 = "));

    Serial.print(packet1.data22);
    Serial.print(F(" flex3 = "));
    Serial.print(packet1.data33);
    Serial.print(F(" flex4 = "));
    Serial.print(packet1.data44);
    Serial.print(F(" flex5 = "));
    Serial.print(packet1.data55);

    Serial.print(F(" accx = "));
    Serial.print(packet1.accxx);
    Serial.print(F(" accy = "));
    Serial.print(packet1.accyy);
    Serial.print(F(" accz = "));
    Serial.print(packet1.acczz);
    Serial.print(F(" con1 = "));

    Serial.println();
  } 

  else {
    Serial.print(F("Send failed."));
  }

}
```

As seen it the two transmitters, I used different addresses. But i'm uncertain if I did it right.

The entirety of my code and .INO files can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CmMq1KVL-1pTN9hsXvt6T4gl655OIH5P). Thank you very much. I'm really hoping for any help it would mean a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you’re reading only a single packet on the receiver side with the expectation that it will contain data from both transmitters; however each transmitter transmits a separate packet. Thus you are reading the data from only one of the transmitters, in this case transmitter 1 since that’s what `available()` defaults to. Check for available packet for *each individual pipe* by calling `available(&pipeNum)` for each transmitter where `&pipNum` Is a reference to a variable containing the assigned pipe number.